# reference on SDE driven by Levy processes

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am reading on the Shephard Nielson model. I am just wondering if there are books on processes driven by jump processes?

Can anyone give suggest a reference book for me on this?

Comment: Are you interested specifically in Levy processes, or book on more general semimartingales is also OK?

Comment: @Ilya I am intersted in SDEs driven by Levy processes. Maybe i should have been more specific on the word "processes". I have some knowledge about Levy processes themselves.

Comment: @Lost1 : As it seems that you financial application in view I recommend the Book by Cont and Tankov untitled "Financial Modelling with Jump Processes" which is really complete. Best regards.